# Force software rendering on iOS Flutter Release build

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to force software rendering on iOS Flutter App release build, since my app got rejected because my app stuck at white screen. I've tested on my own ipad/iphone simulator it works fine, even without internet connection it still works (not stuck at white screen). Is there any other possible cause other than rendering problem?

my dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  image: "^2.0.0"
  args: "^1.5.0"
  dart_config:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/dart_config.git
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  splashscreen: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1
  uuid: ^1.0.3
  intl: ^0.15.7
  http: ^0.12.0
  moment: ^0.0.1
  flutter_web_view: 
    path: flutter_webview
  image_picker_saver: ^0.1.0
  video_player: ^0.7.2
  dio: 1.0.9
  cached_network_image: ^0.5.1
  animated_text_kit: ^1.2.0
  unicorndial: ^1.1.5
  firebase_messaging: ^2.1.0
  percent_indicator: ^1.0.10
  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.4
  device_info: ^0.3.0
  badge: ^0.0.3
  stack_trace: ^1.9.2
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
  url_launcher: ^4.0.3
  package_info: ^0.3.2
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
```

**EDIT** apparently the cause is, `flutter build ios` doesn't default to `--release` (unlike `flutter build apk`), so the archive will make an invalid build that would always fail to install on device or verify by Apple verification team.

Comment: not sure what you're asking because it seems there's 2 problems: you want to enable software rendering and your app stuck on white screen. These might be unrelated with each other as I cannot see any explicit correlation between the two from your explanation

to run with software rendering, the there already `--enable-software-rendering` param. Might be undocumented but often mentioned on flutter github repo

and about your white screen, please post output log

Comment: yeah probably unrelated, the logs are [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26215), and the white screen (apparently it's a crash) only happened when i archive, export, then install the ipa instead of flutter run